# Parse json list with gson

Tags: java, gson

I have the following json string:

```
[["aaa",-1],["awf",1],["gdr",-1]]
```

I want to parse that list into key-value hashmap so it would have entries like this:

```
key: aaa, value: -1
key: awf, value: 1
key: gdr, value: -1
```

I tried different logics with gson but did not succeed. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** Tried this:

```java
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(b, JsonObject.class)
```

and I get the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonArray
```

Comment: GSON comes in handy when mapping JSON to the equivalent object model, but your model needs translation between JSON and Java, so I rather would use a normal JSON parser parsing your array of arrays into a Map.

Comment: Have you considered parsing the JSON as what it actually represents (an array of 2-elements arrays) then mapping that data into your hashmap (with a Stream or a plain old for loop)? It seems to me it'd be easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: You should add a minimal reproducible example. That is to say, the code you tried and what is the error. Otherwise, your question will be closed soon.

Comment: Your JSON is an array of arrays. Can you change it to an array of objects? `[{"aaa": -1}, {"afw": 1}, {"gdr": -1}]`? That way a JSON library would probably create a map easily, but in an array it has no idea what the key and what the value(s) should be.

Answer (score -1):

You can use com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken to convert a json list to a HashMap.

```
String jsonString = "[[\"aaa\",-1],[\"awf\",1],[\"gdr\",-1]]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Integer>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, Integer> fromJson = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
System.out.println(fromJson);
```